# how to print mysql result RESOURCE_ID(7) without mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to print the resource_id without mysql_fetch_array.I dont want to loop through result.I want print only the first row at top.I know mysql has been depreciated.This is for old project.

Comment: Add `LIMIT 1` at the end of the query

Comment: I want to also use the remaining rows in another place which run through fetch array loop but if we use fetch_array twice it will leave the first row.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of arrays in your case

```
$all_rows = array();
.
.     // your query
.
while($dbrow = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
   $all_rows[] = $dbrow;
}

$first_row_array = $all_rows[0]; // first row will be stored here
/* 
   uncomment the below line if you do not want to use the 
   first row again while looping through the remaining 
   rows
*/
/* unset($all_rows[0]); */

foreach($first_row_array as $first_row)
{
    // do something with first row data
}


foreach($all_rows as $dbrow)
{
    // loop through all the rows returned including the first row
}
```

Comment: How is this *not* using `fetch_array`...?

Comment: Either I misinterpreted what the OP was asking or you might have. Of what I understood, all the OP wanted was to extract the first row from the result set separately and later loop through all the rows again. I'm not sure how the usage of `fetch_array` or `fetch_assoc` is applicable here. EDIT: Just read the question again. I think he was referring to not using `fetch_array` the second time to get the remaining rows

Answer (score 0):

A resource in itself is a pretty meaningless type. It only means something to specific functions, like mysql_*. When querying the database, there are certain *resources* allocated on the MySQL server which hold your requested result; PHP doesn't really have access to those results yet. To give you a handle on those resources on the MySQL server, you get a *resource type* variable. It's basically just your ticket, saying *"if you ever want to access that data waiting for you on the MySQL server, use this number."*

So, if you want to output the data from the MySQL server, you will have to `fetch` it from there, e.g. with `mysql_fetch_assoc`. That then returns the data to you which you can print.

If you just want the first result, just call that function once.